# Tweepy StreamingClient custom __init__ / arguments - super() not working

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, super, superclass

I'm looking to stream tweets to json files. I'm using **Twitter API v2.0**, with **Tweepy 4.12.1** and **Python 3.10** on **Ubuntu 22.04**. I'm working with the `tweepy.StreamingClient` class, and utilizing the `on_data()` method.

```
class TweetStreamer(tweepy.StreamingClient):

    def __init__(self, 
                 out_path:str,
                 kill_time:int=59,
                 time_unit:str='minutes'):
        '''
        adding custom params
        '''
        out_path = check_path_exists(out_path)
        self.outfile = out_path 

        if time_unit not in ['seconds', 'minutes']:
            raise ValueError(f'time_unit must be either `minutes` or `seconds`.')

        if time_unit=='minutes':
            self.kill_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60*kill_time)
        else:
            self.kill_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=kill_time)

        super(TweetStreamer, self).__init__()

    def on_data(self, data):
        '''
        1. clean the returned tweet object
        2. write it out
        '''
        # out_obj = data['data']

        with open(self.outfile, 'ab') as o:
            o.write(data+b'\n')
```

As you can see, I'm invoking `super() on the parent class, with the intention of retaining all the stuff that is invoked if I didn't specify a custom **init**.

However, however I try to change it, I get this error when I try to create an instance of the class, passing a `bearer_token` as well as the other arguments defined in `__init__()` :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [106], line 1
----> 1 streamer = TweetStreamer(bearer_token=bearer_token, out_path='test2.json')

TypeError: TweetStreamer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bearer_token'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because you declared that `__init__` does not take `bearer_token` as an argument. You need to pass the keyword arguments your constructor gets to the constructor of the superclass that is expecting them. You can do it using the unpacking operator `**`:

```
    def __init__(self, 
             out_path:str,
             kill_time:int=59,
             time_unit:str='minutes',
             **kwargs):
    '''
    adding custom params
    '''
    # (...)

    super(TweetStreamer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: fascinating. thank you for this answer -- i would never have figured that out / found it by myself.